# Avoiding duplicating sql Switch conditions

Tags: sql, ms-access-2003

(needs to be compliant code down to Access 2003)

Apologies if this is a "doh!" moment (still learning)...as part of a SELECT statement I have the following field called `Total` whose purpose, for each record, is to calculate the total of 4 previous fields. A '0' value is passed to Total if the sum is <1000, if it isn't then the actual sum is passed.

Summarised we have:

```
,IIf(
Switch(……) +
Switch(……) +
Switch(……) +
Switch(……)<1000,0,

Switch(……) +
Switch(……) +
Switch(……) +
Switch(……))

AS Total
```

In its much expanded version it does work, however, this looks cumbersome since it means having to repeat the initial 4 Switch conditions twice (once if <1000 and once if not).

Is there any way to reduce this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to use a subquery:

```
select iif(val < 1000, 0, val)
from (select x.*, (switch() + . . . + switch()) as val
      from x
     ) as x1;
```